# A couple of questions about a distribution (counting) problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I came across this question below

[Number of ways to distribute five red balls and five blues balls into 3 distinct boxes with no empty boxes allowed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148395/number-of-ways-to-distribute-five-red-balls-and-five-blues-balls-into-3-distinct)

My first question is about the solution using PIE. The way I understand it,

First, we name the boxes $A, B, C.$ Then we distribute five blue balls and five red balls into $A, B, C$ with no restrictions. Call the result $X$. Then we distribute five red balls and five blue balls into two boxes with no restrictions. There are three disjoint cases: $\{A, B\}, \{B, C\}, \{A, C\}.$ Call this number $Y$. Then we put five red and five blue balls in a single box with no restrictions. There are three disjoint cases: $A, B, C.$ Call this number $Z$. Thus the final answer is $X - Y + Z. $

If the analysis above is correct, how does it explicitly correspond to PIE which is given as $|(A \cup B \cup C)'| = |U| - (|A| + |B| + |C|) + (|AB| + |AC| + |BC|) - |ABC|$ where $S'$ is the complement of $S, \ U$ stands for universe and $AB$ denotes $A \cap B?$

Had I not seen the solution, I would've done the following,

First put five red balls into the three distinct boxes with no box empty which can be done in $\displaystyle{\binom{5 - 1}{3 - 1}}$ ways. Then distribute the five blue balls into the three distinct boxes with none empty in $\displaystyle{\binom{5 - 1}{3 - 1}}$ ways. Thus by product rule there are $\displaystyle{\binom{5 - 1}{3 - 1}}^2$ ways to do this. What's wrong with this intuition?

Comment: You didn't count all the cases. For example, a case could be that all the red balls is in one box and all the blue balls in the remaining 2 boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be combination of distribution of identical objects with inclusion and exclusion principle.
$$ $$ All 5 red identical can be distributed into 3 distinct box without any restriction is =${7 \choose 5}$=21ways
$$ $$ similarly 5 blue in three distinct box without any restriction is =21ways.
$$ $$ Total distribution without any restriction = 21x21= 441 ways.
$$ $$ let $A_i$ denote box i do not any object.
$$ $$ n($A_i$)=6×6= 36 $$ $$ n($A_i\bigcap A_j$)=1×1=1
$$ $$
Hence when atleast one of the box is empty is
$$n(A_1\bigcup A_2\bigcup A_3)= 3.n(A_i)-3.n(A_i\bigcap A_j)$$
$$=3×36-3×1 =105$$
Hence total required number of distribution = 441-105 
$$ = 336 $$

Comment: Thanks. What kind of elements does $A_i \cap A_j$ contain?

Comment: When particular$ i^{th},j^{th}$ box do no get any balls.